# How can I vertically align a <table> in the middle of a fixed height <div>?

Tags: html, css, xhtml, vertical-alignment

Why does the code below not cause the `<table>` to be vertically-aligned in the middle of the `<div>`?

```
<div style="width: 850px; height: 470px;vertical-align: middle;" align="center">
        <table style="padding-left: 20px; width: 700px; border: 10px groove #0033CC; background-color: #F9F9F9;">
            <tr>
                <td>
                    &nbsp;
                </td>
                <td>
                    &nbsp;
                </td>
                <td>
                    &nbsp;
                </td>
            </tr>            <tr>
                <td>
                    &nbsp;
                </td>
                <td>
                    &nbsp;
                </td>
                <td>
                    &nbsp;
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>
                    &nbsp;
                </td>
                <td>
                    &nbsp;
                </td>
                <td>
                    &nbsp;
                </td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </div>
```

I want the `<table>` in the middle of the `<div>`, but it is at the top! How can I fix this?

Thanks for your future advice.

Comment: W3Schools is a very useful resource for this sort of thing.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Outside of table cells, `vertical-align` sets the vertical alignment of text within a line, rather than the vertical alignment of entire elements like your table.

However, if you set `display: table-cell;` on your `<div>`, that seems to achieve the effect you want.

I’m not sure how many browsers support this though. I’ve checked in Chrome 6, Firefox 2 and Opera 10.5, and they’re fine with it. Internet Explorer could be a different matter.

Comment: thanks 4 ur answer / i test it / but when i used display: table-cell; the width css did not work perfectly / any idea?

Comment: @LostLord: “the width css did not work perfectly” — could you describe *how* it didn’t work?

Comment: hi dear friend / it seems there is no width set and width of that div is 4-5px...

Comment: @LostLord: really? The `<div>` still seems to have the correct width on my test page: http://www.pauldwaite.co.uk/test-pages/4064677/ Which browser are you testing in?

Answer (score 3):

Have you tried "display:flex;"?

```css
div{
    width: 850px;
    height: 470px;
    
    display: flex;
    /* WIDTH and HEIGHT are required */
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
}
td, table{
    border-collapse: collapse;
    border: 1px solid black;
}
```

```html
<div>
    <table>
        <tr>
          <td>Lorem</td>
          <td>Lorem</td>
          <td>Lorem</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>2019</td>
          <td>2018</td>
          <td>2017</td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
<body style="vertical-align:middle">
<table style="display:inline-block">
<!-- your stuff -->
</table>
</body>
```

`table` is a block element.  To get it to vertically align, I think it needs to be displayed as `inline`.  `inline-block` will often give you the best of both worlds in situations like these.  Cheers!

Comment: @Paul: My bad; I misread his question.  I've updated my answer accordingly.

Comment: I think with `display: block`, you’d want `vertical-align: middle` on the `<table>`, not the `<div>`.

Answer (score -3):

Its easy. Always use this >> style="vertical-align:middle" << inside every TD. You can use top, middle and bottom. You can push it in the CSS too.

Answer (score -5):

try this:

```
#centerAligned{
    text-align: center;
    margin-top: 50%;
}
```

it worked for me!!