# How to vertical align a table inside a div

Tags: html, css, html-table, vertical-alignment

I have a background div with set dimensions, which includes a table element.

I'm looking for a way to position the table in the middle-left of the div. Left is easy, middle I can't get to work. This is what I have:

HTML

```
 <div id="background">
      <table>
        //... stuff 
      </table>
 </div>
```

CSS:

```
 #background {
      height: 1000px;
      width: 1000px;
      text-align: left;
      }
```

Can someone tell me how to vertical align the table?

Comment: [What have you tried?](http://mattgemmell.com/2008/12/08/what-have-you-tried/), What have you Googled? There are thousands of tutorials online with the answer you're looking for.

Comment: just fixed it with position relative/position absolute... never mind vertical align.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Div's don't allow vertical aligns typically. The only option would be to make it act like a table cell or do something like margin/padding that will look like your table is vertically aligned.

Comment: correct, just found this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4064677/how-can-i-vertically-align-a-table-in-the-middle-of-a-fixed-height-div

Answer (score 3):

Just position: relative the table within the div and give it top: 50% and left: 50%.

You can take out the left and just use top

http://jsfiddle.net/EZk3T/1/

Answer (score 1):

Using top: 50% will not put it in the middle, you would have to use calc but that would require a fixed height and this never seems to work for me using top: for future reference though, if you want to align horizontally then use this example:

```
width: 300px;
left: calc (50% - 150PX)
```

The - 150px is equivalent to half of the width.