# how to align vertically a dynamic-height div inside another fixed height div

Tags: html, css

I came across a CSS puzzle and I'm searching for the best solution for the following trick:

```
<div class="vertical-wrapper">
    <div class="vertical-content">
        Variable length of text which can be multiple lines
    </div>
</div>
```

I want to align the 'vertical-content' in the middle, no matter how much height it gets through the text lines. Here is the css code provided from the puzzle:

```
.vertical-wrapper{
width: 220px;
min-height: 220px;
background: #red;
overflow: auto;
}
.vertical-content{
    background: #green;
    margin: 10px;
    padding: 5px;
}
```

and here is the [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/2bbz9/) for that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One solution is to transform its `Y-axis` to `-50%` and then apply `margin-top: 50%` to the `.vertical-content`.

### [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/chipChocolate/2bbz9/60/)

```css
.vertical-wrapper {
  width: 220px;
  min-height: 220px;
  background: #cf0000;
  overflow: auto;
}
.vertical-content {
  background: #fff;
  margin: 10px;
  padding: 5px;
  margin-top: 50%;
  transform: translateY(-50%);
}
```

```html
<div class="vertical-wrapper">
  <div class="vertical-content">Variable length of text which can be multiple lines. Variable length of text which can be multiple lines.
    <br />Good luck!</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Was about to upvote when I saw that the 2nd box in the snippet isn't centered somehow. But your logic makes sense...

Comment: @Rhumborl - It is centered, look at the full page or Fiddle.

Comment: I did - http://imgur.com/2erW3Sb is the what the fiddle looks like in Chrome. 34px above, 63px below

Comment: @Rhumborl - Weird! Works perfectly on Firefox when the boxes are displayed `inline-block` and works in all browsers if there is just one box.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `inline-flex` display. Here's the proper CSS:

```css
.vertical-wrapper{
    display: inline-flex;   /*a minor change here*/
    width: 220px;
    min-height: 220px;
    background: #cf0000;
    overflow: auto;
}   
   
.vertical-content{
        background: #fff;
        margin: auto 10px;  /*and here*/
        padding: 5px;
    }
}
```

And [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ue2tmLxh/)

Answer (score 1):

I combined some answers above and some of my own research and I found the answer, thanks to you guys!

**HTML CODE**

```
<div class="vertical-wrapper">
    <div class="vertical-content">
        Variable length of text which can be multiple lines.<br />
        Variable length of text which can be multiple lines.<br />
        Variable length of text which can be multiple lines.<br />Good luck!
    </div>
</div>
```

**CSS CODE**

```
.vertical-wrapper{
width: 220px;
height: 220px;
background: #cf0000;
overflow: auto;
position: relative;
}

.vertical-content{
position: absolute;
top: 50%;
left:10px;
right:10px;
background: #fff;
padding: 5px;
transform: translateY(-50%);
}
```

Comment: Nice one. BTW if this is exactly what you need, and you think it is the best solution, you can mark your own answer as the accepted one.

Answer (score 0):

You are setting a `min-height` on `.vertical-wrapper` but then `overflow:auto`. If you set a fixed height instead, and the text gets too big, it will still get taller and achieve the same thing.

Once the height is fixed, you can vertically align the div using `display:table-cell` and `vertical-align:middle` as described in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4064734/1901857).

```css
.vertical-wrapper{
    width: 220px;
    height: 220px;
    background: #cf0000;
    overflow: auto;
    display:table-cell;
    vertical-align:middle;
}

.vertical-content{
    background: #fff;
    margin: 10px;
    padding: 5px;
}
```

```html
<div class="vertical-wrapper">
    <div class="vertical-content">
        Variable length of text which can be multiple lines.<br />Good luck!
    </div>
</div>

<hr/>

<div class="vertical-wrapper">
    <div class="vertical-content">
        Variable length of text which can be multiple lines.<br />Good luck!
        <p>Variable length of text which can be multiple lines.<br />Good luck!</p>
        <p>Variable length of text which can be multiple lines.<br />Good luck!</p>
        <p>Variable length of text which can be multiple lines.<br />Good luck!</p>
        <p>Variable length of text which can be multiple lines.<br />Good luck!</p>
        <p>Variable length of text which can be multiple lines.<br />Good luck!</p>
    </div>
</div>
```